# wordpress jquery is not defined because the head tag is empty

Tags: plugins, php, jquery

I have googled this error and none of the solution that mentioned in my search results seem to work.
So basically all my pages work fine except the /blog index page which does not load jquery.
The error I get is as follows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined => script.js :2
```

I suspect this is happening because the   tag does not have anything inside it when I inspect the source.

i tried disabling each and every plugin and tested it but the issue persists.

Comment: are you using a custom theme?

Comment: yes this has a custom theme. we received the wp files from the developer(contractor) who converted the site from drupal to wordpress. the problem is the page looks fine on his staged environment. but doesn't work in our environment.

Comment: well could you paste the code (assuming it's in your function.php). especially the line where you see **wp_enqueue_script** followed by a filename of **script.js**. My guess is that this script is called before jQuery is enqueued. Without any code, it's hard to give a good answer.  If you have a `home.php` in your theme folder, paste that as well. I'm trying to figure out where the call to `script.js` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

bynicolas pointed me in the right direction by asking to look into the custom theme.
Turns out the following line was missing in the index.php on the custom theme:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

After adding the above it works fine.